# Каково происхождение имени Ольга?

Tags: этимология, ономастика

Каково происхождение слова Ольга?

Answer (score 3):

Есть три версии происхождения имени Ольга.
По греческой версии оно происходит от слова Ελγα, по германской - это вариант имени Хельга, что в переводе значит "святая", и по русской - Вольга переводится как "чародей", "кудесник".

Comment: Все-таки надо остановиться на германской.
Греческая ставится под сомнение отсутвием прчмого аналога в греческом и временем возникновения (задолго до прияниятя христианства).   
Русская - обычная, имхо,  придумка славянофилов. Ну какая тут может быть "кудесница" в княжеском женском имени?

Answer (score 0):

От Олега - Ольг - Ольга,  а то в свою очередь от ольха, дерево, которое растет быстро и везде, где есть свободное место. В том числе и по берегам рек. Вольно растет. Захватчик.

Ольха

```
ольха о́льха́ диал. также вώльха (Долобко, ZfslPh 3, 101), диал. ёлха вятск., вологодск., ело́ха, нижегор., костром., укр. вíльха́, ḯльха, др.-русск. ольха, сербск.-цслав. єльха, болг. елха́, сербохорв. jóха, jóвa (из *jеоха), словен. jélša, диал. ólša, jólša, чеш. оlšе, слвц. jеlšа, польск. оlсhа, olsza, в.-луж. wólša, н.-луж. wоlšа. Праслав. *jеlьха наряду с *оlьха (см. Мейе, ВSL 25, 161), родственно лит. al̃ksnis, alksnỹs, alìksnis, ẽlsknis "ольха", лтш. èlksnis, àlksnis (Буга, ИОРЯС 17, 1, 16 и сл.), д.-в.-н. elira, erila, нов.-в.-н. Erle "ольха", др.-исл. o<lr, alr, лат. alnus – то же (*alisnos), макед. ἄλιζα ̇ ἡ λεύκη (Гесихий); см. Кречмер, "Glotta", 15, 305; 22, 104; далее сближают с д.-в.-н. ёlо "желтый, рыжеватый"; см. Бернекер 1, 453 и сл.; М.–Э. 1, 68; Мейе, там же; МSL 14, 478; Траутман, ВSW 6; Арr. Sprd. 295; Шпехт 58 и сл.; 115, 199; Виссман у Марцелля 1, 218. Вероятно, это стар. и.-е. основа на -о ж. рода (Мейе). Согласно Перссону (893), колебание *elis- : *olis- носит уже и.-е. характер. Он приводит, помимо балт. форм, еще др.-исл. o<lr "ольха", наряду с jo<lstr "вид ивы", шв. jälster. От ёлха образована фам. Елшин; см. Потебня, ФЗ, 1876, вып. 2, стр. 95. Этимологический словарь русского языка. — М.: Прогресс М. Р. Фасмер 1964—1973
```

wolsa - вольша, вполне осмысленно звучит… созвучно воле.
Белорусский-вольха, алешына. 
Украинский вiльха.

Современные русские имена: 
Александр
Алексей, Алеша, леша;
Ольга, Ольг, Олег;
Алик, Алька;
Олеся, Алиса

Приставка са - ша - шка — ласкательное значение.
Алекса - Алексашка - Сашка - Саша.
Алексей - Алешка - Алеша
Ольша

Ольха - Ольша - Ольга - Олег - Алек
Скорее всего, такая цепочка,  в значении Воля. Иду, куда хочу, расту, где хочу, по своей воле.
Далее с Волгой, как вольная дорога, путь. Булгары - волгари.
 Имя Александр - от о(а)лексы+ рыжий(сандр), Македонский был РЫЖИМ. См. фрески Пеллы.

Comment: behemothus-  похоже считает, что в белорусском напрочь отсутствует русская речь, в том числе и 9-века, осталось только в названии слово БелоРуссия. 
Интересно, а  может ли выразить свои мысли автор комментария более конкретно, что ему не нравится.
Виталина_AL--тоже не мешало бы  указать какие конкретно нарушены правила.